# SQL INSERT STATEMENT, ONLY TWO VALUES INTO A TABLE WHICH HAS MANY COLUMNS

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name (your_column_name, your_id )
VALUES (select your_column_name from another_table, 'abc');
```

the above logic doesn't seem to work, can anyone suggest a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. I believe you want:

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name (your_column_name, your_id ) 
(select your_column_name, 'abc' as your_id from another_table);
```

Comment: using the parentheses wrapping the select statement are redundant

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, you can either do an `insert ... select` or a `insert ... values` but you can't combine the two.  If you want to do a `select`, you'd need an `insert ... select`

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name (your_column_name, your_id ) 
  select your_column_name, 'abc' 
    from another_table;
```